# Hyperledger Fabric performance issue with couchdb

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to invoke a chaincode function. The couchdb is taking almost 15 seconds to serve 3 request to fabric (2 query and 1 write operation)

Here are the peer logs ==> https://hastebin.com/ezihededuq.md

Orderer logs ==> https://hastebin.com/enebuxuval.coffeescript

Chaincode function that was executed ==> https://hastebin.com/uwazokegih.cs

But when I directly query couchdb it only takes few milliseconds

If anyone knows
please help.

---

Here `couchdb` took 5 seconds | line 5 & 6

```
2018-07-25 11:50:47.300 IST [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 15cd HTTP 
Request: GET /assetchain_assetchaincode/_design/lastnameasc/_view/lastnameasc?stale=update_after HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-25 11:50:52.309 IST [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 15ce Exiting handleRequest()
```

Line 9 & 10 `couchdb` took 4 seconds

```
2018-07-25 11:50:52.309 IST [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 15d1 HTTP Request: GET /assetchain_assetchaincode/_design/lastnamedesc/_view/lastnamedesc?stale=update_after HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-25 11:50:56.991 IST [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 15d2 Entering: Got request from 192.168.0.18:60858
```

Line 68 - 69 `couchdb` took 5 seconds again

```
2018-07-25 11:50:57.322 IST [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 160c HTTP Request: GET /assetchain_assetchaincode/_design/request_created_at_sort_asc/_view/request_sorting?stale=update_after HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-25 11:51:02.007 IST [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 160d Exiting handleRequest()
```

line 259-260 `couchdb` took 2 seconds

```
2018-07-25 11:51:02.335 IST [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 1699 HTTP Request: GET /assetchain_assetchaincode/_design/request_sort_name_asc/_view/request_sort_name_asc?stale=update_after HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-25 11:51:04.123 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 169a == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/BlockValidation ==
```

line 293-294 `couchdb` took 2 seconds

```
2018-07-25 11:51:04.125 IST [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 16bb HTTP Request: GET /assetchain_lscc/assetchaincode?attachments=true HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-25 11:51:06.071 IST [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 16bc Entering: Got request from 192.168.0.18:60858
```

line 381-382 `couchdb` took 2 seconds

```
2018-07-25 11:51:07.346 IST [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 1713 HTTP Request: GET /assetchain_assetchaincode/_design/request_sort_name_dsc/_view/request_sort_name_dsc?stale=update_after HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-25 11:51:09.137 IST [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 1714 Exiting handleRequest()
```

line 489-490 `couchdb` took 3 seconds

```
2018-07-25 11:51:09.338 IST [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 177c HTTP Request: GET /assetchain_/statedb_savepoint?attachments=true HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-25 11:51:12.356 IST [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 177d Exiting handleRequest()
```

The peer, couchdb, orderer are hosted each on a separate machine.
The configuration of machines are described below:

Processor: i5
Ram: 8GB
OS: Ubuntu 64bit 16.04 LTS

If anyone have any idea then please let me know

Comment: 1. Are you putting a new key or updating an existing one?
2. Which version of fabric are you using?

Comment: I tried both putting new key or updating existing one. I'm using Fabric 1.1 @arnabkaycee

Answer (score 0):

The write doesn't complete until the block is cut by the orderer. Default time is 2s...

Comment: it is not related to batch time out.